# UITapGestureRecognizer doesn't work on UICollectionView header

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I have a `UICollectionView` with an header.

I want to call the method `headerTapped` when the user tap on the header.

I've tried to add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the header in the `` method like that:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "likesHeader", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! LikesCollectionReusableView

    header.postsCounter.text = "\(self.likedBasicPosts.count)"

    //Adding gesture recognizer
    let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector(headerTapped()))
    tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    header.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)

     return header
}
```

And what happened it that:

When the view load `headerTapped` is being called (without even tapping on the header), and then when I tap on the header it does;t even being called.

`headerTapped()`:

```
private func likesHeaderWasTapped() {
        if self.expandedSections.containsObject(1) {
            self.expandedSections.removeObject(1)
        } else {
            self.expandedSections.addObject(1)
        }
        self.smallPhotosCollectionView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 1))
    }
```

Why is that?

Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't you use #selector in Swift 2.2? How is declared `headerTapped()`?

Comment: @Larme When I use #selector it gives me the error: `Argument of '#selector' does not refer to an initializer or method` and I'll edited my question with `headerTapped()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `headerTapped` method needs to be of the form in this example from the Apple [UITapGestureRecognizer docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/)

Also see the [UIGestureRecognzer docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIGestureRecognizer) for more discussion.

Also, in your `headerTapped` method, you need to check the gesture recognizer `state` so that you only trigger your logic when the tap gesture has ended.

```
func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == .Ended {
        // handling code
    }
}
```

Comment: And how should I call `handleTap(sender:)` as the target of the gestureRecognizer?

Comment: `let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MyClass.buttonTapped))`

OR 

`let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector(headerTapped:))`